# WebInvoke return Json string with extra quotes

Tags: c#, json, wcf, post

I am working on a WCF webservice. 
I need to create a Post service that returns a Json stringhe service is declared as follows:

```
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "GetMatAnalysis",  ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
                                                RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
                                                BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, 
                                                Method = "POST")]
string GetMatAnalysis(Stream image);
```

in this message I am serializing object with using `JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize()`
and then return it.

however when I get the responce there is a extra Double-Quote at the start and at the end of the string. For example I am getting: `"{"results" : 10 }"` instead of `{"results" : 10 }`

I tried to change the return type to `System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message` I get this error:

```
An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a WSDL export extension: System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior contract: http://tempuri.org/:IMyWebServices ----> System.InvalidOperationException: The operation 'GetMatAnalysis' could not be loaded because it has a parameter or return type of type System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or a type that has MessageContractAttribute and other parameters of different types. When using System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message or types with MessageContractAttribute, the method must not use any other types of parameters.
```

How can I make it return a json string without the double quotes?

**Additional information:**

When I use GET request like this:

```
[OperationContract(Name = "Messages")]
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Messages/GetMessage", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
Message GetAdvertisment();
```

The return type is message and it works correctly. The Json string received is correct.

Any help is greatly appreciated. 
Thank you

Comment: I think this is an annoying quirk of MS. Once again they are applying standards using their own twisted logic

Comment: @L.B Thank you it worked. Write it as an answer to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json`, WCF service serializes your returned object as Json.  You also use `JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize()` and you get double serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Return a Stream instead of a string and set the content type of the outgoing response to "application/json; chatset=utf-8". This will return everything properly.

Interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface ITestService
{        
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/GetMatAnalysis")]
    Stream GetMatAnalysis(Stream image);
}
```

Service:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
public class TestService : ITestService
{
    public Stream GetMatAnalysis(Stream image)
    {
        MatAnalysisResult matAnalysis = new MatAnalysisResult { results = 10 };

        string result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(matAnalysis);
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        return new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result));
    }
}
```

The result will be:

```
{"results":10}
```